# Do we have any ways to retrieve the list of process and threads which are in runnable state(not running state) in ubuntu?

Tags: ps, realtime

My requirement is to do dynamic cpu shielding in C program based on the queue length of runnable threads(but not running threads which are waiting for CPU availablity) in Realtime operating systems-(say ubuntu with RT linux patch) scenarios. For example, we can consider the system is configured for **SCHED_FIFO** policy.

I am not able to find any commands to retrieve the number of process which are in wait state, running state, runnable state etc.

The command '**PS -T au**' shows the state of all 'runnable' as well as 'running' threads as 'R'.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.